# If $f(x)$ is continuous in [a,b] and $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$ and $f(x)$ has domain $x\in[a,b]$, where $f(a)=c$, $f(b)=d$, then prove following

Tags: calculus, integration

If $g(x)$ is the inverse of $f(x)$ and $f(x)$ has domain $x\in[a,b]$, where $f(a)=c$, $f(b)=d$, then

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+\int_{c}^{d}g(x)dx=bd-ac$

Now I want to prove it.

**Q-$1$**: Can I conclude that range of $f(x)$ is $[c,d]$ from the given data? I am asking because if we can conclude this, then we can write $\int_{c}^{d}g(x)dx=\int_{c}^{d}g(f(x))d(f(x))$ and we will be able to prove the desired result.

**Q-$2$**: Can I conclude that range of $f(x)$ is $[c,d]$ or $[d,c]$ if it had been given that $f(x)$ is increasing or $f(x)$ is decreasing respectively.

I think in **Q-$1$**, we can't conclude that as at some point in middle of $[a,b]$ we can get a smaller or larger value.

I think in **Q-$2$**, we can say that range of $f(x)$ is $[c,d]$ or $[d,c]$ if $f(x)$ is increasing or decreasing in $[a,b]$ respectively.

But the textbook which I am referring to, over there this condition has not been mentioned, am I missing something here?

Comment: If $f$ is not continuous, then its range can be bigger than $[c,d]$. E.g. $f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x<0.5\\1.5-x&\text{if }0.5\leq x\leq 1\end{cases}$

Comment: $f$ is obviously continuous in $[a,b]$ because it is given that domain of $f(x)$ is $[a,b]$, so at no point in $[a,b]$ it can be undefined or broken. So continuity of $f(x)$ in $[a,b]$  can be derived from given data.

Comment: Draw a picture!

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, I know we can prove by that but for that also $f(x)$ should be increasing or decreasing in $[a,b]$ and the problem is that this condition is not mentioned in the theorem. Do you agree or not?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang, without drawing the picture also, we can prove this but for that $f(x)$ should be increasing or decreasing in $[a,b]$

Comment: The function I gave in my previous comment has $[0,1]$ for domain, the inverse exist $g(x)=f(x)$ but is not continuous. I see nowhere in your post that says $f$ is continuous.

Comment: ok suppose $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, because otherwise break the integration and we don't where $f(x)$ is discontinuous.

Comment: If your function $f$ is continuous, then yes the range of $f(x)$ is $[c,d]$ or $[d,c]$.

Comment: but it can be only when the function is increasing or decreasing in $[a,b]$ right? This condition was not mentioned in the theorem.

Comment: yeah we settled that confusion, let's say $f(x)$ is continuous because otherwise $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: now can we all assume that $f(x)$ is continuous and address the main issue.

Comment: I have edited the question and provided the condition that $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$

Comment: The integral $\int_a^bf(x)dx$ makes sense even if $f$ is not continuous. The hypothesis that $f$ is continuous need to be added to problem. It cannot be deduced.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous, it has domain $[a,b]$ and it is one-to-one (in order to have inverse) THEN $f$ is strictly monotone, it has image $[f(a),f(b)]$ (if $f$ is increasing) or $[f(b),f(a)]$ (if $f$ is decreasing) and its inverse $g$ is strictly monotone of the same nature (if $f$ is increasing / decreasing, $g$ is increasing /decreasing respectively).

Comment: @Ramiro, you mean to say the bijective functions are all either increasing or decreasing functions, if they are continuous right?

Comment: If a function is continuous, defined on an interval and it is one-to-one then it is either increasing or decreasing.  The fact that the domain is an interval is important.

Comment: ok, give me some time, I will just give you a function which is bijective, has domain defined in the interval and it is not either increasing or decreasing.

Comment: ok, sorry I tried to make but I was always getting many-one, you are correct.

Comment: @copper.hat, I have posted the proof ,please see it.

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: I believe I have a different proof, will write it up next year...

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous and has an inverse it is strictly monotonic. Assume for simplicity that
$f$ is increasing.

Note that $[a,b] \times [c,d] = S_1 \cup S_2$ , where $S_1=\{ (x,y) | a \le x \le b , c \le y \le f(x) \} $ and $S_2 =  \{ (x,y) | a \le x \le b , f(x)  < y \le d \}  $. These
are disjoint sets.

It is straightforward to check (using monotonicity) that
$S_2 = \{ (x,y) | c \le y \le d, a \le x < g(y) \}$.

Since $m S_1 = \int_a^b \int_c^d 1_{[c,f(x)]}(y)dy dx = \int_a^b (f(x)-c)dx$ and
$m S_2 =  \int_c^d \int_a^b 1_{[a,g(y))}(x)dx dy = \int_c^d (g(y)-a)dy$ we have
$m([a,b] \times [c,d]) = (b-a)(d-c) = \int_a^b (f(x)-c)dx + \int_c^d (g(x)-a)dx $.

Since $\int_a^b (f(x)-c)dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx -c(b-a)$ and 
$\int_c^d (g(x)-a)dx = \int_c^d g(x)dx -a(d-c)$ we have the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

As we concluded that $f(x)$ will be increasing or decreasing as $f(x)$ is continuous and bijective, so

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)+\int_{c}^{d}g(x)dx$$

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)+\int_{c}^{d}g(f(x))d(f(x))$$

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)+\int_{f^{-1}(c)}^{f^{-1}(d)}x\dfrac{d(f(x))}{dx}dx$$

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)+\int_{a}^{b}xf'(x)dx$$

Integrating by parts:-

$$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)+bf(b)-af(a)-\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$$
$$bd-ac$$

Comment: You are also using the result that says: if $f$ is a monotonic function defined on an interval, then it is differentiable almost everywhere on that interval.  This result is called Lebesgue's Theorem for the Differentiability of Monotone Functions. However this result does **not** ensure that $f(b) - f(a) = \int_a^bf'(x)dx$ and so does not ensure $\int_a^bxf'(x)dx = bf(b) - af(a) -\int_a^bf(x)dx$.

Comment: In fact, consider $h: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ the Cantor function. This function is an increasing (not strictly) function, continuous, $h(0)=0$, $h(1)=1$ and $h'(x)=0$ almost everywhere. 
Let $f: [0,1] \to [0,2]$ be defined as $f(x)=x+h(x)$. This function $f$ is continuous, strictly increasing, $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=2$. We have that $f'(x)=1$ almost everywhere in $[0,1]$. So 
$$ f(1)-f(0)= 2 \neq 1 =\int_0^1f'(x)dx$$
and, using that $\int_0^1h(x)dx= \frac{1}{2}$, we have $\int_0^1f(x)dx=1$ and 
$$ 1f(1)-0f(0)-\int_0^1f(x)dx= 2-0-1=1 \neq \frac{1}{2} =\int_0^1xf'(x)dx$$

Comment: If $g$ is the inverse of $f$ in the comment above, we have 
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx+ \int_0^2g(x)dx = 1+1=2= 1(2)-0(0)$$
However, your proof does not work for this case, because
$$\int_0^2g(x)dx= 1 \neq \frac{1}{2} = \int_0^1xf'(x)dx$$

More precisely, using Riemann-Stieltjes Integral, we have: 

$$\int_0^2g(x)dx=\int_{f^{-1}(0)}^{f^{-1}(2)}xd(f(x)) \neq  \int_0^1xf'(x)dx$$

In order for your proof to work, you must **add** conditions regarding $f$.